# trigger link in CListView from dropdownlist

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I need to trigger link from CListView when change selected value in dropdownlist.

```
$(function () {
    $(".dd").change(function(){
        $('.title').trigger('click');
    });
});

<div class="dd">
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('title', '', $RawData); ?>
 </div>

//view for CListView

 <div class="title" id="">
<?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->naslov), Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/one/two?id1='.$data->id2.'&id2='.$data->id2 ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: What is it that you want to do exactly? Navigate to the linked page? Also, the list view will supposedly contain many links -- which one is it that you are after?

Comment: List in dropdownlist have to be shortcuts of links in CListView. When I selected first item in dropdownlist, then I want to go on page which is linked in first item from CListView.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved the problem

```
$(function () {
    $(".dd").change(function(){
        var valString = $(".dd option:selected").val();
        var link = $('#titID_'+valString+' a').attr('href');
        //alert(link);

        $('#titID_'+valString).bind('click', function() {
                window.location.href = link;
                return false;
            });
        $('#titID_'+valString).trigger('click')
    });
});
```